# Observer pattern in API definition using Franca IDL

Tags: c++, api, design-patterns, observer-pattern, idl

I am researching Franca as IDL for automatic API generation. http://franca.github.io/franca/

In my current API, the observer pattern is widely used. Listener classes and callbacks are defined. I do not find a way to actually model that in Franca IDL.

Is it broadcasts the way to model them? If so, aren't the broadcasts supposed to model interaction between a server and a client?

Comment: please explain your use-case in more detail; what kind of API do you want to model using Franca? do you actually have "client" and "server"?

Comment: I have no client server. Just an API where public object A inherits from ObjectBListener. Object B will trigger callbacks and A will get them.

Comment: without client-server architecture I do not much benefit in using a IDL such as Franca

Comment: I want to be able to auto-generate APIs for Android, iOS, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Franca IDL is primarly just what IDL stands for. You can describe an interface that a service offers. The way how clients grant access to the service is, on the technical level, a matter of the actual code generator and framework that is build on top of the France IDL (e.g. [CommonAPI](https://docs.projects.genivi.org/ipc.common-api-tools/3.1.3/html/CommonAPICppUserGuide.html)).

So your code generator might generate code that makes use of the observer pattern - for example to propagate attribute changes from the service to the clients - but it is not part of the interface description as it should stay independent of the actual technology.

You can also have a look on Franca Deployment model ([Franca User Guide](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B7JseVbR6jvhUnhLOUM5ZGxOOG8) Chapter 6) if the generator needs additional information.